# How do I enable Booked scheduler API?

Tags: phpscheduleit

I need help with enabling Booked Scheduler API. Every time I try to access the scheduler api from the webpage I get this message.

> Booked Scheduler API has been configured as disabled.
>
> Set `$conf['settings']['api']['enabled'] = 'true'` to enable.

But I don't know in which file I should make this change.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you're still stuck in this problem but I will solve it for future consults. To enable the api you have to go to the folder "/config" and edit the "config.php" file that you must have. There you will find that line among much others, so all you have to do is set the value to "true" as indicated in the example.

I hope it helps someone, regards.